# HTML Page render - Correction done by Javascript resize feels a bit jarring

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a landing page that has a header, a sticky footer and a main area with a Video and placeholder image. Using CSS, I do some calculations to make the Video area of the size that is available, but it doesn't work for all screen sizes, so I have to resort to resizing the elements in Javascript via the onresize event.

The problem is that I see the page render at first with element sizes that need correction, and then it gets corrected by javascript almost immediately ( < 0.5 seconds). I see this happening visually and am wondering if there is a way for me to delay the original render and simply see it when the elements have been correctly sized.

In the past I experimented with making the  tag not visible to start and then making it visible in javascript. Is that the best approach to achieve what I am trying ?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @Michelangelo. The code for CSS and Javascript is too big, I'm still working on breaking it down into modules. I posted the question to get thoughts on what the best practice is for something like this. I'm sure what I see is generic and faced by a lot of other web designers. (only that I'm not a front end developer but more of a backend guy, thus the inexperience in this area.)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by hiding the content using `visibility: hidden` in CSS and changing visibility to `visibility: visible` once the JavaScript processing is done.

Comment: Thanks @sunknudsen. I did that in the past and it seemed to work most of the times. I did have a friend test for me and he was not able to see the page, my guess was that this visibility back to enable didn't work on some of the occasions. of course later I found another issue that I was missing a closing </div> in the page. so I don't know if that was the root cause for page not being visible. Anyways, I guess this is the best option I have and I just need to do a lot more testing for it.